# Extracting a lines if a column checks out to be a specific value - Unix

Tags: python, awk, sed

Given that I have a tab-separated file with the first column as some sort of index:

```
$ echo -e "0\tabc\txyz\n1\twhatever ever\tfoobar\n0\t12f2\t1" > test.txt
$ cat test.txt 
0   abc xyz
1   whatever ever   foobar
0   12f2    1
```

And I would like to extract the lines where the index in the first column is specifically 0 or 1.

I can do this in Python:

```
$ python -c "print '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in open('test.txt') if line.split('\t')[0] == '0'])"

0   abc xyz
0   12f2    1
```

**But what is the sed / awk (or any unix tools) equivalent of the short python script?**

Comment: `awk '$1 == 0' test.txt`

Comment: @jordanm you should post that as it's the right awk answer.

Comment: It fails if first field is `00` or `01` (and then some).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers here use regex and suffer from the problem of also matching "01", "11", "12", etc. With `awk`, you can test for string equality:

```
awk '$1 == 0' test.txt
awk '$1 == 1' test.txt
awk '$1 <= 1' test.txt
```

Comment: These too will fail if the first field is `00` or `01`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we are looking for records where *the first column is specifically 0 or 1*:

First some test material:

```
$ cat file
0 yes sir
1 yes sir
10 nope
01 nope
00 nope
```

In awk:

```
$ awk '$1 == "1" || $1 == "0"' file
0 yes sir
1 yes sir
```

These will fail:

```
$ awk '$1 == 0' file
0 yes sir
00 nope
$ awk '$1 == 1' file
1 yes sir
01 nope
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed '/^0\t/!d' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all lines starting with `0`:

```
grep '^0' file
```

Get all lines starting with `0` or `1`:

```
grep '^\(0\|1\)' file
```

Comment: This matches `11`, which probably isn't desireable.

Answer (score 0):

`Awk`  version:

- For leading 0 lines:

  awk '/^0/'
- For leading 1 lines:

  awk '/^1/'

`Sed` version:

- For leading 0 lines:

  sed -n '/^0/p'
- For leading 1 lines:

  sed -n '/^1/p'